# Performing a Union on groups of rows without the same columns. Trying to generate empty histogram bins

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, union, cross-join

I am using MySQL.

I have a table `grades`, that looks like so:

```
course_id grade
101        90
101        100
101        100
102        92
102        85
102        90
```

I have a view that counts how many grades are in each bin, for each class using the following query.

```
SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(grade_bin) as count
FROM
    (SELECT
        course_id, 
        FLOOR(grade/5.00)*5 AS grade_bin
    FROM ranked_grades) as t
        GROUP BY course_id, grade_bin
        ORDER BY course_id, grade_bin ASC;
```

This returns:

```
course_id grade_bin count
101         90        1
101         100       2
102         85        1
102         90        2
```

I want to add empty bins to this view, like so:

```
course_id grade_bin count
101          40       0
101          45       0
...         ...      ...
101          100      2
102          40       0
...         ...      ...
```

So the bins increment by 5, starting at 40, and stopping at 100. My thought was to make a table for empty bins, insert each grade bin and a count of 0, then use `UNION` but I can't get the `UNION` to work, since I don't have the `course_id` column in the empty bin table (nor do I want to - there are a lot and they could change). How would I do a UNION for each group of `course_ids`?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry I had considered that. I went back and forth and the solutions I was developing in the application were not very elegant. I figured handling it in SQL would be faster, if I could mange the query. You still may be right... my approach was definitely optimal.

Comment: that should be *not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have created the table `bin_table` with only 1 column `grade_bin` and values 40, 45, 50, ...., 100 and also that you have a table `cources` with the column `course_id` as primary key, all you have to do is `CROSS` join these tables and `LEFT` join to a query that aggregates on the table `ranked_grades` (no subquery needed):

```
SELECT c.course_id, b.grade_bin, COALESCE(t.count, 0) AS count
FROM bin_table b CROSS JOIN cources c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT course_id, FLOOR(grade / 5.00) * 5 AS grade_bin, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM ranked_grades
  GROUP BY course_id, grade_bin
) t ON (t.course_id, t.grade_bin) = (c.course_id, b.grade_bin)
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct (although it's 'courses', not 'cources'). The query worked and I accepted your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a list of bins.  Then use `cross join` to generate all the rows.  Finally, join in the existing data.

So:

```
SELECT c.course_id, gb.grade_bin, COUNT(rg.course_id) as cnt
FROM (SELECT 40 as grade_bin UNION ALL
      SELECT 45 as grade_bin UNION ALL
      SELECT 50 as grade_bin UNION ALL
      . . . 
      SELECT 100 as grade_bin 
     ) gb CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT course_id
      FROM ranked_grades 
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     ranked_grades rg
     ON rg.course_id = c.course_id AND
        rg.grade >= gb.grade_bin AND
        rg.grade < gb.grade_bin + 5
GROUP BY c.course_id, gb.grade_bin;
```

Note:  This retrieves the courses from the `ranked_grades` table.  You could also use a `courses` table which is presumably also available.

Comment: I will test this - thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I removed the ellipses and I am getting an error. Have not been able to identify it. MySQL Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') gb CROSS JOIN      (SELECT DISTINCT course_id       FROM ranked_grades       )' at line 6

Comment: I have accepted @forpas answer as the solution, as that is the one I was able to get working.

Comment: @nonethewiser . . . The error was a trailing `UNION ALL` on the last row in the subquery.